# REST - Get Resource URI out of Response (NOT ClientResponse)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, cxf, resteasy

How to get a resource URI path/location out of the Response.class? When I invoke my restful service with Apache CXF client API like this:

```
 Response res = resource.post(object);
```

I get back the JAX-RS Response type. CXF doesnt an own implementation of Response like Jersey or RestEasy do. So how to get the URI, where I created my object, out of Response.class?

In Jersey I am dealing with a ClientResponse.class. There I can handle this with:

```
 res.getLocation();
```

RestEasy has a ClientResponse.class as well and I can handle the problem like jersey does.

Comment: This was annoying me greatly today as well. Sadly, I just ended up passing along with `webTarget` to where I wanted to access the URI (a utility logging method) and using `target.uri` there :( Frustrating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jersey ClientResponse gets the `Location` from the headers:

```
/**
 * Get the location.
 *
 * @return the location, otherwise <code>null</code> if not present.
 */
public URI getLocation() {
    String l = getHeaders().getFirst("Location");
    return (l != null) ? URI.create(l) : null;
}
```

The JAX-RS Response provides header information via `getMetadata()`:

```
public MultivaluedMap<String, Object> getMetadata() {
    if (headers != null)
        return headers;

    headers = new OutBoundHeaders();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        if (values[i] != null)
            headers.putSingle(ResponseBuilderHeaders.getNameFromId(i), values[i]);

    Iterator i = nameValuePairs.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        headers.add((String)i.next(), i.next());
    }

    return headers;
}
```

So what I would try is:

```
response.getMetadata().getFirst("Location");
```

(If that doesn't work print the Metadata content. Maybe the key has another name.)

Comment: It does not work on Jersey 2.8. There is no URI in the headers. It maybe because of redirects?